# Issue with SQL statement

Tags: mysql

Following is SQL statement within stored procedure which returns records fine. However, I also need the value for MEMBER_ID. When I add this to the select statement then no records are returned. I tried CAST and CONVERT, but no results. For reference the field MEMBER_ID is the key value in both tables. It is an INT.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(WEBFSS.MEMBERS.LAST_NAME, ", " ,WEBFSS.MEMBERS.FIRST_NAME) As Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _mon THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _mon THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _tue THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _tue THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _wed THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _wed THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS3, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _thu THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _thu THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS4,   
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _fri THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _fri THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS5
 FROM WEBFSS.SCHEDULE
  INNER JOIN WEBFSS.MEMBERS
    ON WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.MEMBER_ID = WEBFSS.MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID
WHERE
  (WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE BETWEEN _mon AND _fri) 
GROUP BY
 WEBFSS.MEMBERS.LAST_NAME, WEBFSS.MEMBERS.FIRST_NAME ;
```

This does not work:

```
SELECT
  SCHEUDLE.MEMBER_ID,
  CONCAT(WEBFSS.MEMBERS.LAST_NAME, ", " ,WEBFSS.MEMBERS.FIRST_NAME) As Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _mon THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS1,
```

Comment: "`SCHEUDLE`"? Looks like you just misspelled your table name. But maybe you just mistyped it as you wrote this post. In the future, please use copy & paste to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: If you got an error, please include the complete error message in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Try to group by `SCHEUDLE.MEMBER_ID` and `CONCAT(WEBFSS.MEMBERS.LAST_NAME, ", " ,WEBFSS.MEMBERS.FIRST_NAME)`:

```
SELECT
  SCHEUDLE.MEMBER_ID,
  CONCAT(WEBFSS.MEMBERS.LAST_NAME, ", " ,WEBFSS.MEMBERS.FIRST_NAME) As Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _mon THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _mon THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _tue THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _tue THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _wed THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _wed THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS3, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _thu THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _thu THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS4,   
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _fri THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.QTY END) AS MEALS5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE = _fri THEN WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.ENSURE END) AS ENS5
 FROM WEBFSS.SCHEDULE
  INNER JOIN WEBFSS.MEMBERS
    ON WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.MEMBER_ID = WEBFSS.MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID
WHERE
  (WEBFSS.SCHEDULE.DATE BETWEEN _mon AND _fri) 
GROUP BY SCHEUDLE.MEMBER_ID, CONCAT(WEBFSS.MEMBERS.LAST_NAME, ", " ,WEBFSS.MEMBERS.FIRST_NAME);
```

When you include an aggregate function in the select with extra columns that are not included in the group by, then mysql will select random values for those columns that are not included in neither aggregate functions nor a group by clause.